# Limiting table column width using only colgroup and col

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, html-table

Working on an Angular 2 project with a table display.

```
<table class="table-frame__table">
    <colgroup>
        <col *ngFor="let col of frame.columns"
             [style.max-width.px]="col.width"
             [style.width.px]="col.width">
    </colgroup>
    <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let row of frame.layout">
        <td *ngFor="let cell of row"
            (click)="selectCell(cell)"
            class="table-frame__cell"
            rowspan="cell.rowLength"
            colspan="cell.colLength">
            {{ Cell Content Are Populated Here }}
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The width of each column is only stored in the columns in our model, the cells themselves are unaware of how wide they are 'allowed' to be, so I cannot limit the width on the td tags or in the contents of the td's.

The contents are editable by the user. When they type enough text it will automatically expand the width of the entire column, is there a way to prevent this using only the colgroup and col tags.

My current CSS is as follows:

```
.table-frame__table {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.table-frame__content {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

td, th {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.table-frame__cell {
  border: 1px solid #A9A9A9;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

EDIT: Found a solution. It actually had to do with the contents of the td which is another component with the following CSS:

```
:host {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.table-frame-cell__content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
 }
```

Comment: you want to limit all columns to a particular width or ?

Comment: Each column is limited to a variable width that corresponds to frame.column[index].width.

Comment: can you create a plunker?

Comment: Found a solution. Will post it in the original.